# Outer product using the quantum mathematica package

Tags: matrix, tensors, products

I am using the quantum *Mathematica* package and am trying to do computations that require me to use the outer (tensor) products of Pauli matrices. I would define this as, for example, `Subscript[\[Sigma], 2]\[CircleTimes]Subscript[\[Sigma], 3]` .

However if I ask *Mathematica* to compute this, it only finds the matrix product of the two operators, not the outer (tensor) product. Does anyone know of a way to do this calculation with *Mathematica* still recognizing the operators as Pauli matrices, i.e. rather than writing them in matrix form or in Dirac notation?

Comment: Closely related (though not using any packages): [Pull out scalars from NonCommutativeMultiply in commutator of SU2 spin algebra](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/63811/245). The answer there should also apply here: use `KroneckerProduct`. So in other words, don't use *Mathematica*'s tensor functions. See also [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/110715/245).

Comment: Thank you, I'll give that a go!