# Forming Kronecker products for "non-adjacent" vector spaces

Tags: matrix, performance-tuning

In quantum mechanics, we often want to build operators acting on multiple particles by simply "Kronecker-ing" operators from the single-particle spaces. That is, if I have some matrix $A$ acting on particle one and $B$ on particle two, the appropriate matrix acting on their joint space is just $A\otimes B$. Mathematica gives you an easy way to do this with the function KroneckerProduct.

However, given a matrix $C$ which acts on the join particle space, it is not generically possible to find an $A$ and $B$ such that $C=A\otimes B$. This means that some operators cannot (naively) be built with Mathematica's native KroneckerProduct function: if I have three particles, and an operator $U$ which acts non-trivially on particles one and three but which does not factorize, I do not know how to tell Mathematica to build that matrix. Note that this difficulty does not occur for an operator acting on "adjacent" vector spaces: if $U$ instead acts on spaces two and three, we can write the total matrix as $\mathbb{I}\otimes U$, where $\mathbb{I}$ is the identity on particle 1.

I can think of a few ways around this, but they are all pretty inefficient. Are there any particularly good/clean ways to work this with Mathematica's native matrix functions?

Comment: It depends a lot on the form of the expression for the operator $U$ that you start with. Without an example, it's not likely that you'll get an answer that matches your needs. See e.g. [my answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/63829/245) for spins where the question was about nearest-neighbor interaction but my code can (I think) handle the general case too. Another related answer is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149211/245).

Comment: That's a fair point, but the problem is that the matrices I'm dealing with are random, and change with each instance of my code. I'll look at your references though - thanks!

Comment: You can `ArrayReshape` result of `KroneckerProduct`, then `Flatten` it with "shuffled" dimensions. This is equivalent to transposition on corresponding tensor product space. So if you have three spaces $V_1$, $V_2$, $V_3$ with dimensions `n1`, `n2`, `n3`, and `u13` matrix with `Dimensions`: `{n1 n3, n1 n3}` acting on product space $V_1 \otimes V_3$, then `Flatten[ArrayReshape[KroneckerProduct[u13, IdentityMatrix[n2, SparseArray]], {n1, n3, n2, n1, n3, n2}], {{1, 3, 2}, {4, 6, 5}}]` will give you corresponding matrix acting on  $V_1 \otimes V_2 \otimes V_3$, with identity acting on $V_2$.

Comment: Yes, this worked very well - thank you! I was using a similar strategy with TensorProduct but overall this was easier to code/understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any $m \times n$ matrix $u$, with $m = \prod_{i=1}^k m_i$ and $n = \prod_{i=1}^l n_i$ (where $k,l,m_1,\ldots,m_k,n_1,\ldots,n_l \in \mathbb N$), represents operator between [product spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_product_of_vector_spaces) $\bigotimes_{i=1}^k V_i$ and $\bigotimes_{i=1}^l W_i$. Such matrix can be converted to matrix representing corresponding operator on spaces with shuffled constituent spaces: $\bigotimes_{i=1}^k V_{\sigma(i)}$, $\bigotimes_{i=1}^l W_{\delta(i)}$ (where $\sigma$ and $\delta$ are arbitrary permutations of respective index sets).

In *Mathematica* this can be done using [`ArrayReshape`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ArrayReshape.html) and [`Flatten`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Flatten.html) functions:

```
Flatten[
  ArrayReshape[u, {m@1, m@2, ..., m@k, n@1, n@2, ..., n@l}],
  {{σ@1, σ@2, ..., σ@k}, {k + δ@1, k + δ@2, ..., k + δ@l}}
]
```

---

In case from OP we have three spaces $V_1$, $V_2$, $V_3$ and a matrix `u13` representing [endomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endomorphism) on $V_1 \otimes V_3$. Let's create example matrix `u13`, not representing a [simple tensor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_tensor), by adding two independent [`KroneckerProduct`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerProduct.html)s:

```
ClearAll[n, u, v]
n@1 = 2; n@2 = 3; n@3 = 4;
Function[mat, Table[(mat@i = Array[Subsuperscript[mat, Row@{##}, i] &, {n@i, n@i}]) // MatrixForm, {i, 3}]] /@ {u, v}
(u13 = KroneckerProduct[u@1, u@3] + KroneckerProduct[v@1, v@3]) // MatrixForm
```

Now we would like to create matrix acting on $V_1 \otimes V_2 \otimes V_3$, that acts as `u13` on $V_1 \otimes V_3$ "part" and as some arbitrary matrix `u@2` on $V_2$. We can do it by first creating matrix acting on $V_1 \otimes V_3 \otimes V_2$ using `KroneckerProduct[u13, u@2]` and then swap $V_3$ and $V_2$ using `ArrayReshape` and `Flatten`. Since in case of our example `u13` matrix we know its decomposition to simple tensors, we can easily verify our result by comparing it with sum of appropriate Kronecker products:

```
Flatten[
  ArrayReshape[KroneckerProduct[u13, u@2], {n@1, n@3, n@2, n@1, n@3, n@2}],
  {{1, 3, 2}, {4, 6, 5}}
]
% == KroneckerProduct[u@1, u@2, u@3] + KroneckerProduct[v@1, u@2, v@3] // Expand
(* True *)
```

Finally to get matrix acting as identity on $V_2$ we just need to use [`IdentityMatrix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IdentityMatrix.html) instead of `u@2`:

```
Flatten[
  ArrayReshape[
    KroneckerProduct[u13, IdentityMatrix@n@2],
    {n@1, n@3, n@2, n@1, n@3, n@2}
  ],
  {{1, 3, 2}, {4, 6, 5}}
]
```

---

All used functions have specialized versions working with [`SparseArray`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html)s:

```
Flatten[
  ArrayReshape[
    KroneckerProduct[u13, IdentityMatrix[n@2, SparseArray]],
    {n@1, n@3, n@2, n@1, n@3, n@2}
  ],
  {{1, 3, 2}, {4, 6, 5}}
]
(* SparseArray[...] *)
```

and [packed arrays](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496/14303):

```
On@"Packing"
Flatten[
  ArrayReshape[
    KroneckerProduct[
      RandomReal[{-1, 1},{n@1 n@3, n@1 n@3}],
      IdentityMatrix[n@2, WorkingPrecision -> MachinePrecision]
    ],
    {n@1, n@3, n@2, n@1, n@3, n@2}
  ],
  {{1, 3, 2}, {4, 6, 5}}
] // Developer`PackedArrayQ
(* True *)
Off@"Packing"
```

so discussed method can benefit from these optimizations.